# How could I ADD a column in SQL, without ALTER, ADD Functions?

Tags: mysql, sql

In this MySQL challenge, your query should return all the people who report to either Jenny Richards or have a NULL value in ReportsTo. The rows should be ordered by Age. Your query should also add a column at the end with a title of Boss Title where the value is either None or CEO. Your output should look like the following table.

[image]

Somebody Can help me, please...

Comment: Looks like homework, your homework

Comment: This is `MySQL` challenge so why does it have a Postgres tag?

Comment: "column" can mean a column in an actual table, but can also mean one of the fields returned by a select.  here they mean the latter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like all you're missing is the new column:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, ReportsTo, Position, Age,
    CASE 
    WHEN ReportsTo Is Null THEN 'None'
    ElSE 'CEO'
    END as 'Boss Title'
```

Etc..